# How to redirect from a fragment to next page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

So basically,whenever i will click on the beginners section column ,it should redirect me to next page.I have attached   the images of my xml page of exactly how it looks and also attached the the code of home fragment.java code and also attached the mainpage.xml code.Actully I am bemused how exactly should i figure out the code .

[image: this is my home fragment]
so basically when the user will click on beginners calligraphy column it should redirect to next page i.e.the next page I have attached.

[image: this is my beginners calligraphy section]

this is my HomeFragment.java code

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

   
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }




    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }
}
```

This is my MainPage.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".mainpage">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/Pink"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView"
                android:layout_width="950dp"
                android:layout_height="550dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:background="@color/purple_200"
                android:text="     BEGINNERS CALLIGRAPHY"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/DarkBlue"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="210dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                android:text="PHOTOS"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/purple_700"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                android:text="VIDEOS"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/purple_700"/>


        </RelativeLayout>



        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="949dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:rowCount="3">

            <!-- Row 1 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:background="@color/Purple">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b1" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b2" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            <!-- Row 2 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b3" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="190dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b4" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            <!-- Row 2 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b5" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b6" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b7" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b8" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b10" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="130dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b11" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b12" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b1" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `onCreateView` to the following code:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        view.findViewById(R.id.your_beginning_text_id).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainPageActivity.class));
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: hi@sank,i updated the code,Please try this.